# react storybook jest snapshots leads to an error Cannot find module '../../package' from 'node.js'

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I want to combine storybooks and jest snapshot testing, but I don't get it working.
As soon as I follow the doc and add the Snapshot.test.js, it leads to following error, when I run npm test.

```
FAIL ./Storyshots.test.js Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module '../../package' from 'node.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js:60:16)
```

anyone has a clue / hint if this is a failure of implementation or a bug?
thnx a lot!

this is my jest configuration, it my gives a hint?

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": "",
    "transform": {
      ".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/vendor/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "moment",
      "jasmine-expect-jsx",
      "fbjs",
      "enzyme",
      "expect",
      "cheerio",
      "htmlparser2",
      "lodash",
      "domhandler",
      "object.assign",
      "define-properties",
      "function-bind",
      "object-keys",
      "object.values",
      "es-abstract"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Did you solve this one ?

Comment: I would like to read a solution...

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and my solution was add "json" into "moduleFileExtensions", just like this:

```
...
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "jsx",
  "json"
],
...
```

Seems like the file 'package' was not a js[x] file, but a json one, and jest refused to load it.